# Sphinx search error when indexing

Tags: sphinx

Getting errors when trying to run or update sphinx via java (specifically, in my unit tests).  This is causing nothing to get indexed or returned.

`FATAL: binlog: log open error: failed to open ./binlog.001: No such file or directory`

`WARNING: could not open pipe (GetLastError()=2)`

Answer (score 1):

Found that, wherever the command to start sphinx is executing (in my case, the java project's directory), there's 2-3 `binlog.*` files created.  One of them being a lock.  I deleted these files then it all worked again as expected.